# What is the use of def first(columnName : String) : Column in Spark SQL?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

**def first** is present as part of org.apache.spark.sql Functions.
I see it getting used in many places. Sample code :

```
  override def extractPersonDataset: DataFrame = {
    super.extractPersonDataset
      .withColumn("marketplace_id", lit(marketplaceId))
      .groupBy(joinColumns.head, joinColumns.tail: _*)
      .agg(
        collect_list("college_id") as "college_ids",
        collect_list("nickname") as "nickname",
        collect_list("type") as "types",
        first("warehouse_id") as "warehouse_id",
        first("operating_model") as "operating_model",
        first("type") as "type",
        first("has_membership")  as "has_membership"
      )
  }
```

I searched many blogs and the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.3.1/api/sql/index.html#first) but none provided me a clear understanding of how it works. Can someone please explain what it does ?

Answer (score 0):

For me it has these usages :

**in agg-clause after groupBy:**

I use `first` as an alternative to put a column in the `groupBy` clause. This makes sense if the value is constant per grouping, or it just does not matter. As the ordering before groupBy is not garanteed to be conserved by the `groupBy` (as for my knowing), you cannot use it to get the first value, it just takes *any* value.

**With window-functions:**

Here you can use it to get the real first value given the ordering of your frame. E.g. if you have attributes time,measured temperature you can get the first measured temperature with `first($"temperature").over(Window.orderBy($"time"))`. Note that you can achieve the same with min/max in combination with structs (`min(struct($"time",$"temperature")).over(Window...)`), then extract temperature after minimizing `time`), but this is kind of a hassle. This is also more powerful than min/max because you have to option to skip nulls.